# fs.createWriteStream error:ENOENT

Tags: node.js, express, upload, multipart, dir

I use connect-busboy to handle file uploading, here is the code

```
req.busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {


    var type = mimetype.split('/')[1]
    var newName = (new Date()).valueOf();
    var saveTo = path.join(__dirname, '../../userUpload',req.user._id+'', newName+'.'+type);

    file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(saveTo,{flags: 'w'}));

});
```

as you can see, I tried to save the uploaded file in a dynamic dir(named with user._id), and a new file name;

but it gives me an error says

```
"Error: ENOENT, open '\userUpload\53a65fde4e22939811aa306d\1404636837084.mp4' "
```

but when I manully create the user._id dir first, it will work, so fs.createWriteStream can not handle the dynamic dir right?

how can i do this?

Comment: You need to ensure the path exists before creating a file there.  I'd use something like `mkdirp` module.  In your code, I'd probably also use `path.resolve` instead of `path.join` though that won't fix your problem here.

Comment: that's the point, I need to save the uploaded file in each user_id named folder,can mkdirp module achieve this?

Comment: You should extract the directory from the computed path, create the folder if it's not already there, THEN create the write stream.

Answer (score 4):

The directory you are trying to read does not exist! Make sure that the path exists.